# Custom Random sorting of ArrayList of Objects based on an attribute

Tags: java, collections

I have a List of POJO. I want to sort this list based on one attribute in a custom order given in the requirement document. This attribute is of String type. There is no natural ordering possible, since the required order is not following alphabetical or any other order. Is there any way to sort this apart from doing it manually ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a comparator along with a defined **sort order** (This was something I looked for). This will give me the list sorted in the order I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

What you mean by manually? You can always do

```
Collections.sort(yourList, new Comparator<String>(){
//implement your compare method in the way your doc describes it
});
```

Answer (score 0):

yes. Write your own `Comparator` to *custom sort your elements* and then pass it to `Collections.sort()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement Comparable interface and override the compareTo() method.

For example: Suppose if you want to sort a student list based on student ID then you can do it as:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Student stu) {
    return (this.id - stu.id);
}
```

Comment: But the order has to be custom, say I have a list of String containing values A, B, C, D. I have to display them as B,D, C, A. It is not based on any other parameter. I cannot use comparator or Comparable in this case. Can I ? Its just a display order.

Comment: @LadyBird In your question, it is clearly mentioned as you need sorting order based on an attribute. Else if you dont want them to sort then you can go ahead straight away based on insertion order i.e., the items will be in the order of insertion.